# separate each uppercase word with space

Tags: java, string

I want to convert a sentence to a string, in which all words are separated by spaces and only the first word starts with an uppercase letter.
For example, the string “StopAndSmellTheRoses.” would be converted to “Stop and smell the roses.”

When I compile it, why it did put space between each capital word?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment8 {

    public static String editing(String sentences) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length(); i++) {
            char c = sentences.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                sentences.concat(" ");
            }
        }
        return sentences;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("sentence.txt"));
        String orignal;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            orignal = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(orignal);
            String edit = editing(orignal);
            System.out.println(edit);
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` is immutable. `String.concat` doesn't modify the String - it returns a new String with the other string appended to it. You might do `sentences = sentences.concat(" ")` although it's more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` when manipulating a String many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.concat` gives you a new String, which you would have to save to some variable. Use `StringBuilder` instead, which is more efficient.

```
public static String editing(String sentences) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(sentences.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < sentences.length(); i++) {
        char c = sentences.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            sb.append(" ");
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Strings are immutable**. If you want to do this you can do like:

```
public static String editing(String sentences) {
    String str = sentences.charAt(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < sentences.length(); i++) {
        char c = sentences.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            str = str + " ";
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        str = str + c;
    }
    return str;
}
```

This is one simple way - it can be optimised. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: yeah, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Appending Strings to each other is not the efficient way to go when manipulating the same string many times.

Comment: @singh.indolia can you illustrate str = str+" "; meaning

Comment: str = str + " ";  means we are just appending the space char in original string and again assigning it to str. in that case Objects will create in constant pool and GC will erase all left out objects. Here object creation will be more but GC will handle it out.